# How can I get a song tabbed?

Tags: tablature, transcription

There's a song I've been dying to play, relatively simple, but I'm not good enough to figure out how to tab it. How can I get a song tabbed if I can't do it myself?

Comment: quick query - have you googled already? There are a huge amount of tunes already online as tablature:-)

Comment: I have looked for it, it's a rather obscure song apparently. The lyrics aren't even available online.

Comment: @kylex - Edited to remove the pay offer, this isnt the place for that; just ask the question, maybe someone will fill your request to some extent.  Refer you to @Jeff Atwoods answer here; http://meta.guitars.stackexchange.com/questions/102/are-questions-regarding-how-to-play-song-valid - if you cant find it on the internet, then its a valid question

Comment: If you could name the song, and/or link to a youtube video, that might help.

Comment: I made this a real question, and it now suits neilfein's excellent answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're talking about is a *transcription service*. However, these can be expensive, and the ones I found on a quick Google are geared towards musicians who want to put music or tabs on their own websites. Paying someone to make what's essentially sheet music of a song you don't own (I assume this is not music you own the rights to) brings up all sorts of copyright problems. You have a few options. My answer assumes you can't find tab for this song online:

- Ask a friend how to play the song. Most communities of musicians have a few people who are very good at figuring out songs from the recordings.
- Buy the sheet music; even if you don't read music, it'll have chords and lyrics and some even have guitar tabulature. This is your best option, and the most legal.
- Learn how to figure out the music on your own. Except for the most complex music, learning how to do this isn't all that hard, but it is a skill that takes time to develop.
- Ask the musician or composer. Many obscure or local musicians will be accessible in this way.

Comment: No it's not music I own, but neither is it available to purchase. The quandary of copyright.

Comment: Is it possible you can contact the composer or their estate and simply ask?

Comment: @Neil: I have, but have not heard back from them.

Comment: @Neil: Follow-up, the lead singer just sent me a pretty detailed email telling me how to play the song, and the tuning he uses. So frickin' awesome!

Comment: That's great! Glad to hear it.

Comment: @kylex - Glad you found what you where looking for, this might still be an acceptable answer since point 4 of @Neil Fein's answer says contact the the musician/composer.  All the other points are also good advice, although they didn't work for you.  Would be interested to know which band/musician/artist it is actually.

Comment: @DRL - I cheated a *little*, I added the last point after kylex's answer to my question in the comments.

Comment: @DRL: It was from a solo project by Sim Redmond.